# Creating an alias for in fish shell: The file 'vim' is not executable by this user

Tags: vim, fish

I'm trying to create an alias for `vim` to execute `vimx`. After creating a new terminal when I try to auto complete `vi`, I get the following error:

```
fish: The file 'vim' is not executable by this user
/usr/local/share/fish/functions/__fish_complete_vi.fish (line 4): begin; command vim --version 
                                                                                 ^
in . (source) call of file “-”,
    called on line 37 of file “/usr/local/share/fish/functions/__fish_complete_vi.fish”,

in function “__fish_complete_vi”,
    called on line 3 of file “/usr/local/share/fish/completions/vim.fish”,
    with parameter list “vim”

in . (source) call of file “/usr/local/share/fish/completions/vim.fish”,
    called on standard input,

in command substitution
    called on standard input,
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the built in auto complete in fish for vim thinking that the vim command actually now exists (even though its just an alias).

My fish config contains the following:

```
function vim
    command vimx $argv
end
```

Comment: What version of fish are you running? My __fish_complete_vi function first checks if "vim" is a command.

Comment: My fish version is `fish, version 2.1.2`.

Comment: Does your /usr/local/share/fish/functions/__fish_complete_vi.fish file look like this: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/functions/__fish_complete_vi.fish

Comment: It did not, this was the diff: https://gist.github.com/travisperson/f91a528d6968bdf58575, if you'd like to create an answer I'll accept it.